# Show/Hide multiple divs on anchor click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I need to show/hide the content of 3 separate divs when clicking an anchor.

The markup looks like this:
*Div 1*

```
<div class="media pull-left">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="media pull-left is-hidden">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

*Div 2*

```
<div class="media-aside pull-right">
    <h4>heading 4</h4>
    <p>Text...</p>
    <p class="call-to-action"><a href="someurl">url</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-aside pull-right is-hidden">
    <h4>heading 4</h4>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
    <p class="call-to-action"><a href="someurl">url</a></p>
</div>
```

*Div 3*

```
<div class="media-thumb ">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-thumb is-hidden">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
</div>
```

The jQuery looks like this:

```
$('.media-thumb a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('is-hidden').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Essentially, I want to remove the `is-hidden` class from the divs which it's applied to and add it to the others, effectively toggling the content on and off when clicking the anchor.

How can I expand on the above code to do what I need?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: Please, creating a test case keep it simple, we don't have time to read Lorem ipsums or other contents. Keep it simple, will be more readable and people will love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traverse methods are incorrect as is the `is-hidden` selector ( missing dot prefix for class)

`find()` searches within an element, but you are wanting the element itself

Following will cover the case for the `<a>` tag click. It isn't clear what behavior you want regarding other elements with `is-hidden` class. Obviously you can't clcik on one if it is hidden

Try This

```
$('.media-thumb a').click(function(){
   /* if wanting to remove "is-hidden" from all others*/
    $('.is-hidden').removeClass('is-hidden').show();
   /* hide this one*/
   $(this).closest('.media-thumb').addClass('is-hidden').hide();

    return false;
});
```

`closest()` will look up the tree until selector is found. Is cleaner than `parent().parent()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector :visible,  Eg.

```
$('div:visible').addClass('is-hidden')
```